# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException using Stanford Parser and Jetpack Compose

Tags: java, android, android-jetpack-compose, stanford-nlp, graphviz

I want to display a graph for a parsed sentence using graphviz. So I have a class in which the sentence is parsed and returns a Png file:

```
fun createDependencyTree(sentence: String): File {
    // Load the parser model
    val lp = LexicalizedParser.loadModel("spanishPCFG.ser.gz")

    // Tokenize the sentence
    val tokenizerFactory: TokenizerFactory<CoreLabel> =
        PTBTokenizer.factory(CoreLabelTokenFactory(), "")
    val wordList = tokenizerFactory.getTokenizer(StringReader(sentence)).tokenize()

    // Parse the sentence
    val parseTree = lp.apply(wordList)

    // Get grammatical structure and typed dependencies
    val tlp = PennTreebankLanguagePack()
    val gsf: GrammaticalStructureFactory = tlp.grammaticalStructureFactory()
    val gs = gsf.newGrammaticalStructure(parseTree)
    val dependencies: Collection<TypedDependency> = gs.typedDependenciesCCprocessed(true)

    // Generate DOT format from dependencies
    val dotGraph = dependencies.joinToString("\n") { it.toString() }

    // Save DOT format to a file
    val dotFile = File("dependency_tree.dot")
    dotFile.writeText(dotGraph)

    // Convert DOT to PNG using Graphviz
    val pngFile = File("dependency_tree.png")

    Graphviz.fromFile(dotFile)
        .render(Format.PNG)
        .toFile(pngFile)

    return pngFile
}
```

Then, I've got a JetpackCompose clas in which the pngFile is displayed in a column:

```
@Composable
fun secondScreenText(navController: NavHostController, text : String?) {

    val scaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState()



    Scaffold(

        scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(
                title = { },
                backgroundColor = Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
                contentColor = Color(0xFF000000),
                elevation = 0.dp,
                navigationIcon = {
                    IconButton(onClick = {
                        if (text!! != "") {
                            navController.popBackStack()
                            navController.navigate(AppScreens.FirstScreen.route)
                        }
                    }) {
                        Icon(Icons.Default.ArrowBackIos, contentDescription = null)
                    }
                })
        }
    ) {
        Box(
            contentAlignment = Alignment.CenterStart, modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(Color(0xFFFFFFFF))
        ) {
            Column(
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .padding(start = 40.dp, end = 40.dp, top = 40.dp)
            ) {

                Text(
                    text = "Análisis",
                    fontFamily = Inter,
                    fontSize = 28.sp,
                    modifier = Modifier.weight(0.25f)
                )

                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
                        .background(Color(0XFFF0F0F0), shape = RoundedCornerShape(25.dp))
                        .weight(1f)
                        .padding(start = 20.dp, end = 20.dp, top = 20.dp),
                    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                ) {
                    Column(
                        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
                    ) {
                        AutoResizedText(text = text!!, modifier = Modifier.weight(1f), maxLines = 
                      
                        val pngFile = createDependencyTree(text)

                       
                        Image(
                            painter = rememberImagePainter(data = pngFile.toURI().toURL()),
                            contentDescription = null,
                            modifier = Modifier.size(200.dp) 
                        )
                    }

                }

            }


        }

    }
}
```

The problem I've got is that when opening the app and parsing the sentence, instead of displaying the png it crashes with this error
 `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No head rule defined for sentence using class edu.stanford.nlp.trees.UniversalSemanticHeadFinder in (sentence...)`
I would appreciate any help.